# OpenPop.Net - The server did not respond

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using OpenPop.NET and I am trying to download the emails from the server. But, it is giving the below error message In the meantime, I could configure and download the mails without any issues in Outlook by using the same settings that I did with OpenPop.NET.

The server did not respond with a + response. The response was: "-ERR Command is not valid in this state."

```
FetchAllMessages(smtpserver, 110, false, emailId, password);


public static List<Message> FetchAllMessages(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl, string username, string password)
    {
        using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

            client.Authenticate(username, password);

            int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

            List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);

            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
            }

            return allMessages;
        }
    }
```

throwing exception in client.Authenticate(username, password);

Comment: What did you try? Maybe post some code.

Comment: exception is throwing in 
client.Authenticate(username, password);

Comment: What the exception says ? and what Pop3Client you use ? can you post here the page of this module ?

Comment: I am using 'OpenPop.Net' Pop3Client and the exception is below.

The server did not respond with a + response. The response was: "-ERR Command is not valid in this state."

Comment: Code I have already post on top

Comment: Finally I managed to do this by setting the authendication mode to basic